# What is the SQL code for suppressing the pop up warning boxes from displaying in a MS Access Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have a simple delete all query that is embedded in a macro. When I click the macro it always ask, are you sure you want to delete x rows? All I need is the SQL code to suppress the message, NOT THE VBA CODE. Google results only pull the vba code and I need the SQL code. Any help is highly appreciated! The code is below:

```
DELETE *
FROM [New History];
```

Very simple, just need to know what the SQL code for suppressing warnings are, not the DoCmd.SetWarnings False method used to suppress it in VBA. Again, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: A more neutral way of phrasing this question might have been along the lines of "Is there an SQL *equivalent* to setting `SetWarnings` to False`?". Just because you *want* a feature to exist, doesn't necessarily mean that it does.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is for data manipulation, not for any UI related tasks, such as showing/hiding messages.

There's no such SQL code.

However, when using an embedded macro, there is the SetWarnings action, under System Command, only visible if *Show All Actions* has been clicked.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. When I put the Set Warnings above the OpenQuery (To Open my query and run it) It doesnt work.

Comment: You should use _SetWarnings_ with _RunSQL_. Run your query inside the embedded macro using _RunSQL_.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved the issue myself. The SetWarning can be applied in the macro you just have to set wherever the file is located at to be a Trusted Location. Then it worked.